# Android, Kotlin: switching fragments via bottom navigation bar causes error

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, reload

The app starts perfectly ok, as shown in the picture below. But it looks "ridiculous" after switching to other fragments by clicking the bottom navigation bar. For example: The app starts ok (as shown in the below picture), but if I click the second button of the bottom navigation bar and then click the 1st button of the bottom navigation bar to go back to the same fragment, it shows only half of the spinner2 and my RecyclerView is hidden. What is the problem here? Please help to solve this issue.

app start picture:
[image]

picture after switched by clicking the bottom navigation bar.
[image]

qponFragment.kt

```
class qponFragment : Fragment() {

    var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    var myRef = database.getReference("SUBMIT")


    var countryloaded = ""
    var cityloaded = ""

    lateinit var spinnerOne : Spinner
    lateinit var spinnerTwo : Spinner

    val countryArray = arrayOf("選擇地區","香港","澳門","台灣")
    val taiwanArray = arrayOf("選擇城市","臺北市","新北市","桃園市","臺中市","臺南市","高雄市","基隆市","新竹市","嘉義市","新竹縣","苗栗縣","彰化縣","南投縣","雲林縣","嘉義縣","屏東縣","宜蘭縣","花蓮縣","臺東縣","澎湖縣","金門縣","連江縣")
    //val japanArray = arrayOf("選擇城市","東京","大阪","名古屋")
    var tempArray = mutableListOf<String>()

    //var databaseRef: DatabaseReference?=null

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {



        //databaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_qpon, container, false)

    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        qponRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        qponRecyclerView.adapter = QponAdapter()

        val location = Location(activity!!)

        spinnerOne = view?.findViewById(R.id.spinner1) as Spinner
        spinnerTwo = view?.findViewById(R.id.spinner2) as Spinner


        //SpinnerOne
        spinnerOne.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, R.layout.item, countryArray)

        //SpinnerTwo
        var dataAdapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,  R.layout.item, tempArray)
        spinnerTwo.setAdapter(dataAdapter)

        spinnerOne.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {

                var countrySeleccted:String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()
                //println(textItem)

                if (countrySeleccted == "香港") {

                    location.saveCountry(countrySeleccted)
                    location.saveCity("empty")
                    //println(location.loadCountry())
                    //hide
                    spinnerTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                    qponRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                }

                else if (countrySeleccted == "澳門") {

                    location.saveCountry(countrySeleccted)
                    location.saveCity("empty")
                    //println(location.loadCountry())

                    //hide
                    spinnerTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                    qponRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                }

                else if (countrySeleccted == "台灣") {

                    location.saveCountry(countrySeleccted)
                    tempArray.clear()
                    tempArray.addAll(taiwanArray)
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

                    //show
                    spinnerTwo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                    qponRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                }

                else {

                }

            }
        }

        //hide spinner2
        spinnerTwo.setVisibility(View.GONE)

        spinnerTwo.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {
            }

            override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
                var citySelected: String = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString()

                if (citySelected=="選擇城市"){

                }
                else {
                    location.saveCity(citySelected)
                    //println(location.loadCountry())
                    qponRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                    //println("kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk")
                    println(citySelected)
                }
            }
        }

        //check sharedPre data
        if (location.loadCountry() != "empty") {
            println(location.loadCountry())
            //println(location.loadCity())

            countryloaded = location.loadCountry()

            if (countryloaded == "香港") {
                spinnerOne.setSelection(1, true)
            }
            else if (countryloaded == "澳門") {
                spinnerOne.setSelection(2, true)
            }
            else if (countryloaded == "台灣") {
                spinnerOne.setSelection(3, true)

                cityloaded = location.loadCity()
                val indexNumber:Int = taiwanArray.indexOf(cityloaded)
                //println(indexNumber)
                if (indexNumber != -1) {
                    tempArray.clear()
                    tempArray.addAll(taiwanArray)
                    dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    spinnerTwo.setSelection(indexNumber, false)

                }
            }
            else {
                qponRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            }
        }
        else {
            qponRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        inflater!!.inflate(R.menu.qpon_menu, menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        val id = item?.getItemId()
        when (id) {
            R.id.item1 -> createToastMessage("Selected item 1")
            R.id.item2 -> createToastMessage("Selected item 2")
        }
        return true
    }

    private fun createToastMessage(message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }




    inner class QponAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<qponFragment.QponCustomViewHolder>() {

        var listOfTutorial = TutorialList().list



        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return  listOfTutorial.size
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): QponCustomViewHolder {

            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val cellForRow = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.qpon_layout, parent, false)
            return qponFragment.QponCustomViewHolder(cellForRow)

        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: qponFragment.QponCustomViewHolder, position: Int) {

            var videoName = listOfTutorial[position].name
            var videoImage = listOfTutorial[position].image
            var videoLink = listOfTutorial[position].youtubeLink

            holder.itemView.startDate.text = videoName
            holder.itemView.enddate.text = videoLink

        }
    }

    class QponCustomViewHolder(v: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {

    }


}
```

result of console:

```
05-27 23:35:35.143 32734-32734/? I/com.gph.qpon: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
05-27 23:35:35.416 32734-32734/? W/com.gph.qpon: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
05-27 23:35:36.884 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/com.gph.qpon: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
05-27 23:35:37.108 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Suspending all threads took: 161.965ms
05-27 23:35:37.808 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
05-27 23:35:37.811 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/chatty: uid=10094(com.gph.qpon) identical 10 lines
05-27 23:35:37.811 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
05-27 23:35:38.107 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
05-27 23:35:38.146 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
05-27 23:35:38.269 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: 1286666166
05-27 23:35:38.277 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
05-27 23:35:38.280 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
05-27 23:35:38.281 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-27 23:35:38.358 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Collection enabled
    App package, google app id: com.gph.qpon, 1:580019907416:android:f13bd2cc37b8f29d
05-27 23:35:38.358 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11910
05-27 23:35:38.359 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
    To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.gph.qpon
05-27 23:35:38.359 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
05-27 23:35:38.523 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon V/FA: onActivityCreated
05-27 23:35:38.568 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Connecting to remote service
05-27 23:35:38.608 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:38.609 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:38.684 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-27 23:35:39.005 32734-32756/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Unsupported class loader
05-27 23:35:39.022 32734-32756/com.gph.qpon I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
05-27 23:35:39.176 32734-32756/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Unsupported class loader
05-27 23:35:39.320 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/System.out: 台灣
05-27 23:35:39.320 32734-32756/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
05-27 23:35:39.449 32734-32758/com.gph.qpon D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
05-27 23:35:39.481 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
05-27 23:35:39.537 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-27 23:35:39.606 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 104368397
05-27 23:35:39.698 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
05-27 23:35:39.774 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=-5988656651441943046}]
05-27 23:35:39.947 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;-><init>()V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromAssetManager(Landroid/content/res/AssetManager;Ljava/lang/String;IZIII[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->addFontFromBuffer(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;I[Landroid/graphics/fonts/FontVariationAxis;II)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->freeze()Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;->abortCreation()V (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/Typeface;->createFromFamiliesWithDefault([Landroid/graphics/FontFamily;II)Landroid/graphics/Typeface; (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:40.287 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
05-27 23:35:40.588 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
    android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
05-27 23:35:40.588 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-27 23:35:40.588 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-27 23:35:40.604 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xec604980: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
05-27 23:35:40.608 32734-32745/com.gph.qpon I/com.gph.qpon: Background concurrent copying GC freed 9787(823KB) AllocSpace objects, 2(40KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 2MB/5MB, paused 1.295ms total 525.335ms
05-27 23:35:40.666 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:35:40.755 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/System.out: 臺南市
05-27 23:35:40.794 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:35:41.866 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1140ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=104369627325154, Vsync=104369643991820, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=104369658095247, AnimationStart=104369658270247, PerformTraversalsStart=104369658295247, DrawStart=104369691217247, SyncQueued=104369698042247, SyncStart=104369716740247, IssueDrawCommandsStart=104369817322247, SwapBuffers=104370695723247, FrameCompleted=104370787021247, DequeueBufferDuration=265000, QueueBufferDuration=9950000, 
05-27 23:35:41.892 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon D/FA: Connected to remote service
05-27 23:35:41.893 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
05-27 23:35:41.913 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/InputMethodManager: Ignoring onBind: cur seq=361, given seq=360
05-27 23:35:41.914 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/Choreographer: Skipped 68 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
05-27 23:35:42.284 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1509ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=104369694884664, Vsync=104370828217952, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=104370834439247, AnimationStart=104370834490247, PerformTraversalsStart=104370834506247, DrawStart=104370974064247, SyncQueued=104371020262247, SyncStart=104371020345247, IssueDrawCommandsStart=104371020509247, SwapBuffers=104371156415247, FrameCompleted=104371204379247, DequeueBufferDuration=1583000, QueueBufferDuration=13778000, 
05-27 23:35:44.908 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getTransitionAlpha()F (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:44.981 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/View;->mViewFlags:I (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:44.984 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->setTransitionAlpha(F)V (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:44.986 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->suppressLayout(Z)V (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:44.988 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->setLeftTopRightBottom(IIII)V (light greylist, reflection)
05-27 23:35:46.580 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: JNI critical lock held for 25.695ms on Thread[1,tid=32734,Runnable,Thread*=0xf05f4000,peer=0x740091f0,"main"]
05-27 23:35:46.610 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: JNI critical lock held for 19.723ms on Thread[1,tid=32734,Runnable,Thread*=0xf05f4000,peer=0x740091f0,"main"]
05-27 23:35:46.628 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/System.out: 台灣
05-27 23:35:46.776 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon W/com.gph.qpon: JNI critical lock held for 21.868ms on Thread[1,tid=32734,Runnable,Thread*=0xf05f4000,peer=0x740091f0,"main"]
05-27 23:35:46.975 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/System.out: 臺南市
05-27 23:35:47.401 32734-32752/com.gph.qpon V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
05-27 23:35:51.999 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:35:52.427 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon I/chatty: uid=10094(com.gph.qpon) RenderThread identical 1 line
05-27 23:35:52.607 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:35:53.013 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:35:53.046 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/System.out: 基隆市
05-27 23:35:53.304 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:35:53.661 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:35:58.679 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:00.619 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/System.out: 台灣
05-27 23:36:01.017 32734-32734/com.gph.qpon I/System.out: 基隆市
05-27 23:36:03.000 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:03.371 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:03.554 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:07.340 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:07.467 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon I/chatty: uid=10094(com.gph.qpon) RenderThread identical 1 line
05-27 23:36:07.969 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:10.939 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:11.199 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:11.359 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
05-27 23:36:12.997 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon I/chatty: uid=10094(com.gph.qpon) RenderThread identical 2 lines
05-27 23:36:13.165 32734-32760/com.gph.qpon D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xec604980: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xd5bff0f0)
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mFirebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics? = null

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_qpon -> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_qpon)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_black)
                createQponFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_me-> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_me)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.logged)
                createMeFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_tool -> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_tool)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.logged)
                createToolFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.navigation_tutorial -> {
                //message.setText(R.string.title_tutorial)
                actionBarIcon(R.drawable.tutorial)
                createTutorialFragment()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Obtain the FirebaseAnalytics instance.
        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)

        actionBarIcon(R.drawable.ic_title_black)


        createQponFragment()
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    fun actionBarIcon(imageName:Int) {

        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar))
        my_toolbar.setLogo(imageName)

        if (imageName == R.drawable.ic_title_black) {
            my_toolbar.setTitle("")
        }

        if (imageName == R.drawable.logged) {

            my_toolbar.setTitle("login name")

        }
        if (imageName == R.drawable.tutorial) {

            my_toolbar.setTitle("Tutorial")

        }


    }

    val manager = supportFragmentManager



    fun createQponFragment() {
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = qponFragment()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()


    }

    fun createMeFragment() {
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = meFragment()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }

    fun createToolFragment() {
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = toolFragment()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }

    fun createTutorialFragment() {
        val transaction = manager.beginTransaction()
        val fragment = tutorialFragment()
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentholder,fragment)
        transaction.addToBackStack(null)
        transaction.commit()
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please add your code for Activity and Navigation view. That will help to see the fragment switching code.

Comment: i updated the code code for Activity and Navigation view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50551850/kotlin-android-bottom-navigation-fragment-setretaininstancetrue/50581667#50581667 ... check this